# Kestrel Webserver in .Net 6.0: REST-API to old native single-Threaded Library

Tags: c#, multithreading, rest, kestrel-http-server

I need to bring an API for an old existing product to the web. It will be a REST API written in C#.
I need a process via API call because my existing library is definitely single-threaded. But of course I could reuse a process. So I thought of a kind of process pool in the background, which processes the API calls.

Basically, I have two ideas:
Is there a way to configure Kestrel as a web server for this? If it would use a process for each HTTP request, it wouldn't be perfect yet (the initialization of the API is slow and 32-bit only) but a good start.

The only alternative I could think of would be to manage a pool of worker processes myself and transport the tasks and results there via memory-mapped files....

None of this is really nice, but I have to deal with the old API somehow.
Do you have any other ideas or how would you do it?

Thanks for your help.

Ich habe schon ein bisschen mit den Kestrel-Optionen rumgespielt, wobei da nichts richtig Sinn macht ausser:
AllowSynchronousIO = true;

Comment: What do you mean by "existing library is definitely single-threaded"? Does the library use non-threadsafe singletons/globals? Or just that it contains classes that are not thread safe? A normal assumption is that any static methods/properties are thread safe, and anything else is not, unless otherwise documented.

Comment: *manage a pool of worker processes* I do exactly this ... but I'm using old framework and comunicate using WCF via NetNamedPipe (target api is using own threads implementation and is written in clarion)

Comment: The Lib is a black box for me. The documentation explicitly states that the API is not thread-safe. Everything is implemented statically but not stateless in the lib.

NamedPipes should not work in my case because the processor architectures do not fit. Or I would also have to run the WebApi x86!